# Create Script to Update Record on the basis of Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Structure:

1) Campaign

```
Camp_Code int           - Primary Key
AssignTo  int
CreatedBy int
Status    int
```

2) Company

```
CompanyID  int          - Primary Key
Name       varchar(100)
Camp_Code  int          - Foreign Key
AssignTo   int
```

One Campaign has many Company

Now I need to create script to update the Company Table
I need to update the AssignTo field of the Company Table.

[image]

I need to update only those Company whose Camp_Code Status is 0.

Update of the AssignTo(Company) is based on the Camp_Code(Company) and Camp_Code(Campaign)

Here you can see if the AssignTo(Campaign) field is empty then it takes value of the CreatedBy(Campaign) field.

Please help me...

Comment: you could utilize `cursor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
UPDATE co SET co.assignto=COALESCE(ca.AssignTo, ca.CreatedBy)
FROM company co
JOIN (select * FROM campaign WHERE status=0) ca ON(co.camp_code=ca.camp_code)
```